# I got aTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, error-handling

in fucntion `getLink(urls)`, I have `return (cloud,parent,children)`
in main function, I have `(cloud,parent,children) = getLink(urls)` and I got error of this line: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

parent and children are all `list` of http links. since, it is not able to paste them here, parent is a list contains about 30 links; children is a list contains about 30 items, each item is about 10-100 links which is divide by ",".

cloud is a list contain about 100 words, like that:  ['official store', 'Java Applets Centre', 'About Google', 'Web History'.....]

I didnot know why I get an error. Is there anything wrong in passing parameter? Or because the list take too much space?

```
#crawler url: read webpage and return a list of url and a list of its name
def crawler(url):
    try:
        m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        msg = m.read()
....
        return (list(set(list(links))),list(set(list(titles))) )
    except Exception:
        print("url wrong!")

#this is the function has gone wrong: it throw an exception here, also the error I mentioned, also it will end while before len(parent) reach 100. 
def getLink(urls):
    try:
        newUrl=[]
        parent = []
        children =[]
        cloud =[]
        i=0

        while len(parent)<=100:

            url = urls[i]
            if url in parent:
                i += 1
                continue
            (links, titles) = crawler(url)
            parent.append(url)
            children.append(",".join(links))
            cloud = cloud + titles
            newUrl= newUrl+links
            print ("links: ",links)
            i += 1
            if i == len(urls):
                urls = list(set(newUrl))
                newUrl = []
                i = 0

        return (cloud,parent,children)
    except Exception:
        print("can not get links")


def readfile(file):
    #not related, this function will return a list of url 

def main():
    file='sampleinput.txt'
    urls=readfile(file)
    (cloud,parent,children) = getLink(urls)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You might have an other `return` in the function or an implicit `None` as the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way that your function ends without reaching the explicit `return` statement.

Look at the following example code.

```
def get_values(x):
    if x:
        return 'foo', 'bar'

x, y = get_values(1)
x, y = get_values(0)
```

When the function is called with `0` as parameter the `return` is skipped and the function will return `None`.

You could add an explicit `return` as the last line of your function. In the example given in this answer it would look like this.

```
def get_values(x):
    if x:
        return 'foo', 'bar'
    return None, None
```

**Update after seing the code**

When the exception is triggered in `get_link` you just print something and return from the function. You have no `return` statement, so Python will return `None`. The calling function now tries to expand `None` into three values and that fails.

Change your exception handling to return a tuple with three values like you do it when everything is fine. Using `None` for each value is a good idea for it shows you, that something went wrong. Additionally I wouldn't print anything in the function. Don't mix business logic and input/output.

```
except Exception:
    return None, None, None
```

Then in your main function use the following:

```
cloud, parent, children = getLink(urls)
if cloud is None:
    print("can not get links")
else:
    # do some more work
```

Comment: I try to revise the code and add a simple try:...expect exception, and it is an exception there. the error is also there. I am not so sure how to figure it out T_T

Comment: Break down your code to a minimal example and add this to your question. Just saying "There is an exception, what should I do?" is the same as asking "I'm ill, what medicine should I take?". Give us details to work with.

Comment: I added related code to the question. It will add more comment in code soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @b1694621: Check my edits. If you feel that my answer is a solution for your problem you might consider to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Thx. the tips are helpful